# Camel - how to pass exchange property to function to() / endpoint?

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have this code:

```
        from("direct:incoming")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
            .setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, simple("${property.token}"))
            .to(String.format(COLOR_DECODE_PATH, properties.getBaseUrl(), "green"))
            .process(exchange -> {
                log.info("Colour decoded successfully.");
                String colour = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                exchange.setProperty("colour", colour);
            })
            .to("HERE I NEED TO SET LIKE THIS: www.someurl.com/${colourProperty} from above");
```

I've tried with ${property.colour} but it's not working like that.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
All I needed is to use toD() instead of to().

D stands for dynamic.

And this works now:

```
toD("www.someurl.com/${property.colour}")
```